# How to resolve classes with source src-jar library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I have added this jar file to my project's build path under "libraries": 
http://sunet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/jeplite/jeplite/jeplite-0.8.7/jeplite-0.8.7a-src.jar
and cannot get Eclipse to resolve ANY of the included classes.

Packages are visible, but no classes.

Error message is:
"JEP cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Can you post the entry from your .classpath.  I'm guessing you just don't have the source attached.  From the build path editor, you can attach source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, it should be on the build path if its a source tree .... Remember , a jar is just a glorified zip file, so be sure that the binaries are actually in your jar file.  The steps to test are

1) unzip the jar file

2) if its source : then either try adding it to your build path, or just directly import the source folders into your project

3) if you see class files in the jar, then it should be okay to add them to "libraries"

Comment: I thought the last tab "order and export" was responsible for adding it to the build path. I'm really confused right now but unzipping and importing worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is only a jar containing the source code. You need a jar with the compiled classes in it. Try the [jeplite-0.8.7a-bin.jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jeplite/files/jeplite/jeplite-0.8.7/).

Comment: yes, but I wanted to use the source files so I could change implementations if needed.

Comment: Then you should extract the source jar into a separate folder inside your project and mark it as a source folder in the project preferences. (by renaming the source jar's file extension to .zip you can extract it with the zip tool of you choice)